# Display an Error for invalid input in JAVA

Tags: java, input, integer

I have written a JAVA program that takes input from the user and check if the user has entered the correct thing or not. I have taken the input from the Scanner class. If the user enters an invalid character like a String, I want to display 'Invalid Input'.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner takeInteger = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int enteredNumber = takeInteger.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is a valid input? what did you try until now?

Comment: A valid input is an integer.

Answer (score 4):

Just ask the `Scanner` whether the next input is a valid int value, e.g.

```java
Scanner takeInteger = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number");
while(!takeInteger.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input: " + takeInteger.next());
}
int enteredNumber = takeInteger.nextInt();
```

This will retry the operation until the user entered a number. If you just want a single attempt, use something like

```java
Scanner takeInteger = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number");
if(!takeInteger.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input: " + takeInteger.next());
}
else {
    int enteredNumber = takeInteger.nextInt();
    // ... proceed with the input
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get an Exception that is `InputMismatchException` when an invalid input is passed.(i.e except integer value),you can use a try-catch block to hold the exception and inform the user about the invalid input. [Try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) [, Catch block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)

```
    import java.util.*; 

    Scanner takeInteger = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    try{
       int enteredNumber = takeInteger.nextInt();
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Enter a valid input");
    }
```

Comment: It says that 
Cannot resolve symbol 'InputMismatchException'

Comment: @Hardik I thought you may have imported the package java.util using the wildcard import java.util.* but it looks like that you have imported only the Scanner class you can use this class ->   import java.util.InputMismatchException;

Answer (score 1):

You can use Exception handling for the same.

```
public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner takeInteger = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter a number");
         try {
             int enteredNumber = takeInteger.nextInt();
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Invalid Input");
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: When I implement the following code, it works. But let's say that I want to print out the addition of the numbers. When I take an input ( the second number ) and print it using System.out.println, for 'enteredNumber ,it says that 'Cannot resolve symbol 'enteredNumber''

Comment: @Hardik It seems you are taking another input or performing addition outside 'try' block . Try doing this inside the ' try ' block only after you have taken the first input .

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `try-catch` block in your program to check if the user's input is a number or not.

```java
        Scanner takeInteger = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        String input = takeInteger.next();
        int enteredNumber;
        try
        {
            enteredNumber = Integer.parseInt(input); // Input is a number
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong Input!"); // Invalid input
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `.nextLine` method of the Scanner class and then parse to the desired type.

Example:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        String line = sc.nextLine();

        try {
            int enteredNumber = Integer.parseInt(line);
            System.out.println("You have entered: " + enteredNumber);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
    }
}
```

Result with a number:

```
Enter a number
12
You have entered: 12
```

Result a text:

```
Enter a number
abcd
Invalid Input
```